# I need to be able to cancel a long running NHibernate query that just reads data

Tags: c#, nhibernate

So I have searched the interwebs and S.O. but I can't seem to find an answer to my problem. I see some places where people can cancel things because they are working with an IQueryable but in my case I have a repository and I am returning a list but I would like to be able to cancel the call to the query which is just returning data - Hmm, I don't know I explained that very well. Hopefully this code snippet should make it more clear.

```
 public class EdiRepository : GenericRepository<EdiEventLog, Guid>, IEdiRepository
{
    private readonly ISessionStorage _sessionStorage;
    private ISession _session;

    public EdiRepository(ISessionStorage sessionStorage)
        : base(sessionStorage)
    {
        _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        //Uhm, this doesn't seem like the right thing to do. 
        _session.Dispose();
    }

    public IList<EdiEventLog> GetAllLogs(List<String> eventTtypes)
    {
        _session = GetSession();

        var query = from q in _session.Query<EdiEventLog>()
                    where eventTtypes.Contains(q.EventType)
                    select q;

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

If this is redundant and I have just missed it please point me in the right direction but everything I have seen assumes that you are returning and IQueryable not a List.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `_session.CancelQuery();` (from a different thread of course, since your query thread will be blocked at the query call). It will throw a database specific query cancelled exception.

Note that this only works if your query is still running on the database. It won't cancel anything if the query call is already creating .NET objects from the returned data.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, as I don't want any results if they cancel.

Answer (score -1):

i would implement my own cancelation method which will return partial results more quickly

```
public IEnumerable<IList<EdiEventLog>> GetAllLogs(List<String> eventTtypes)
{
    _session = GetSession();
    const int pagesize = 1000;
    int page = 0;
    var query = from q in _session.Query<EdiEventLog>()
                where eventTtypes.Contains(q.EventType)
                orderby q.Id   // to make sure repeated queries return consistent results
                select q;

    IList<EdiEventLog> results;
    do
    {
        results = query.Skip(page * pagesize).Take(pagesize).ToList();
        page++;
    } while(results.Count > 0);
}
```

and use it

```
foreach(var someLogs in GetAllLogs(eventTypes))
{
    AddToGui(someLogs);
    if (userCanceled)
        break;
}
```